# Control the CPU usage during TSQL query- sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, limit, cpu

I have some heavy queries that are running offline on a sql database to manipulate data.
the queries are running and sometimes take a significant part of the computer resources.
Is there a way to control/adjust the CPU usage on in a given query / stored procedure?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per query you can use [MAXDOP](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/15/sql-server-maxdop-settings-to-limit-query-to-run-on-specific-cpu/) to limit number of CPUs used queries (when parallelism applies)

You can't throttle CPU time or %

If you have one CPU only, then your option is upgrade. However, CPU bound queries generally indicate poor quality code ir lack of indexes etc...

Comment: Resource Governor throttles CPU doesn't it? e.g. [scenario 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933944.aspx)

Comment: @Martin: er.. never used Express which is where this kinda stuff used to be. Not looked at it for SQL Server 2008

Comment: Actually only available on Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions so good chance it's not applicable to the OP.