# Delay a SQL Server 2000 query until processor is below 50% utilization using a query or sproc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a several very expensive queries which seem to hog resources that seems to put the system over the top.

Is there a delay function I can call to wait until processor resources come back down in SQL Server 2000 - 2008?

My eventual goal is to go back and make these more efficient, use a sproc, but in the meantime I need to get these to work asap because I'm rewriting legacy code.

Comment: How many CPUs (cores more exactly) do you have in the server?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question...is it not possible to schedule these to run at a specific low-usage time, like at night for example? and store the results for later use?

Comment: Only one core.  The main problem is that the same query is being run over and over again to perform different aggregate functions; I'm sure when then query was first run with a small dataset it appeared to run very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Busy int
       ,@Ticks int
SELECT @Busy=@@CPU_BUSY
      ,@Ticks=7777  --<you have to determine this value based on your machine
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' --10 seconds

WHILE @@CPU_BUSY-@Ticks>@BUSY
BEGIN
    --too busy, wait longer
    @BUSY=@@CPU_BUSY
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' --10 seconds
END

EXEC YourProcedureHere
```

to determine the @Ticks value, just write a loop to print out the difference between @@CPU_BUSY values every 10 seconds.  When the system is at your low load, use this value as @Ticks.

Comment: If the first query runs again, you're back to square one. And if you have several calls to the 2nd query, then you'll using some (a little, but still some) resources for the WHILE/WAITFOR during a busy first query. Clever, but not sure this is good for busy system

Comment: You need a SET here btw SET @BUSY=@@CPU_BUSY. Also +1, never knew you could do this.

Comment: I would hope that they run this as a scheduled job at the most likely "low" time and it it loop over the wait until it is actually low.  You duplicate this code for the second query after the `EXEC YourProcedureHere`.  If this is for an interactive application where the queries are "on demand" then you will need to actually tune those queries and forget about these "delay" parlor tricks.

Comment: ---You'll need to apply this to all calls to control the expensive queries which could lead to a call backlog. Finally (for now!) this won't actually stop 2 expensive calls starting around the same time, before CPU usage ramps up.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control or throttle CPU except for higher editions of SQL Server 2008.

Your best option seems to be to set options to allow only half (or less) your CPUs to be used for any query. This can be done 2 ways

- at the server level for all queries using ["max degree of parallelism Option"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007.aspx)
- per query, for offending query with [MAXDOP hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

Also see:

- KB article "[General guidelines to use to configure the MAXDOP option"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329204)
- SO question: [Control the CPU usage during TSQL query- sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5485421/27535) (not a duplicate of this)

Edit:

The question would be: do you want to delay execution (with all the issues like CommandTimneout, user response time etc) or improve concurrency for all queries

This answer should improve concurrency: I usually deal with client apps and I can't make a business user wait.

When delaying execution, you also have to delay all queries (say to disallow the expensive queries from running) which reduce concurrency throughout as calls will back up. And you'll have to be careful about 2 expensive queries starting around the same time

Comment: In this case they are running aggregates on the same base query, so it really needs to be re-written. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of here to actually kick things off in quiet times is to use scheduled tasks and `osql` to execute your statements. Scheduled tasks has to option to run when idle.

I'm not sure about the 50% bit though.

This strategy shouldn't be too sensitive to SQL version either.